# Is there a C++ dialect without "standard bugs"?

Tags: c++

Today I was listening to a number of talks about dark sides of C++. One them was  held by a man who was participating in the creation of the new C++ standard (Nikolai Jossutis). I'm fascinated by the many things in language, which make it easier to misuse. And for me personally it seems that C++ is actually fine if there wasn't backward comparability, which didn't allow to fix "bugs in the standard".

Hypotethically let's say I want an language dialect of C++ that is not backward compatible with the standard C++. It removes components considered dangerous, it doesn't compile something which is almost always results in UB.

I don't want to give any concrete examples, but I'm fine with everyhing which will make code safer. I already treat warnings as errors in the strictiest provided by the compiler way and use static analysis, along with ASan, etc..

UPD: I'm speaking about something very similar to C++ and it's characteristics. If I think about Java, it isn't suitable for me, because of VM. I'm asking about dialect of C++, not very different language, like Java or Rust. Rust is fine, because it compiles to native code, but I'm asking about dialect, not new language.

Comment: Java???????????

Comment: In `g++`, the options [from here onwards](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-Weffc_002b_002b) are not enabled by `-Wall`, but might be of interest. The `-Weffc++` option in particular is interesting, though I don't think it has been kept up-to-date.

Comment: There are also checks for the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) (maintained by Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter) available in [clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/).

Comment: Well, if it is not backward compatible and removes old and ugly stuff that would certainly be a different language.

Comment: I've always wanted something like what you describe, but I think it would be hard to find agreement on what "standard bugs" are.  Do you still want near-compatibility with C?

Comment: @jamesdlin I'd say that I would like to have a C dialect "without standard bugs" as well. The lack of cooperation between C and C++ standard committees is amusing.

Comment: But... but... `C++` is perfect...

Comment: If you remove dangerous components, you remove everything. Overflow has UB, pointer manipulation can bring UB easily, there is nothing easier than breaking the ODR...

Comment: That cannot exist, since compile-time detection of UB can quite easily be proven undecidable (see [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem))

Comment: No. (This space intentionally left blank)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:  The compiler needn't detect UB.  The language design shouldn't include any UB.  That is, it should require some specific behavior for everything that C++ (or C) currently leaves (or declares) undefined.  This would generally be a performance reduction, since UB is currently the basis for a lot of optimizations that would be impossible to do.

Answer (score 2):

you could try D https://dlang.org/...

Or have a look at the Misra C++ rules https://www.perforce.com/resources/qac/misra-c-cpp, there are also code checkers available

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but no. D started out as a clean-sheet attempt, but it quickly picked up its _own_ historical ballast. Misra is based on C++03, which is ludicrously out of date - and that's being friendly. It is designed for C90 and just barely acknowledges the existence of C++.

Comment: IME MISRA is something you are forced to work with, not something you choose to work with.